# Number of possibilities: A nip of 4 digits and one letter

Tags: permutations, combinations

I think the result is $10^4 \cdot 52$.
Am I right?

Comment: What is a "nip"?  $10^4\cdot 52$ counts the distinct selections of an ordered sequence of four digits, with replacement, followed by selection of one letter (case sensitive).  (So for example, $1234X$ or $2441x$ but not $A9990$.)  Is that what you seek to count?

Comment: A nip is like a password for a credit card

Comment: The word you're looking for is "PIN" - personal identification number.

Comment: NIP is a permutation of PIN silly @SeanRoberson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for the number of strings of the form four digits followed by an uppercase/lowercase letter. Then you are correct. There are $10$ choices for each digit and $52$ choices for the last symbol. Hence there are
$$
10^4 \times 52
$$
ways.

Comment: A comment should suffice; "yes, you are correct"  No need to agree it's correct and then walk through a "do-over" only to repeat the asker's work. (or maybe you sought to take up space and pretend it's an answer.)  It's clear the asker is correct, and a simple confirmation is all s/he has sought.

Comment: @amWhy then in what way could an answer ever be added to a question like this in order to remove it from the queue?  There is no option to close a question as "*no need to answer since op has it correct.*"  What would you consider a more appropriate "answer" to a question like this?